# Crop images using jQuery fileupload

Tags: jquery, file-upload, crop, image-resizing, jquery-file-upload

I'm just started implementing file upload functionality and was wondering on what is the best way to add cropping functionality.

Basically, what I want is for users to be able to crop their images following my given aspect ratio. What I currently have is a functional file upload using jQuery fileupload plugin. When I select a file, it automatically uploads the file to my backend through ajax and does some things (save image, generate thumbnails, etc). I've checked some plugins regarding front end cropping functionality and found that jQuery imgareaselect fits my requirements.

So my question is, how do I fit the cropping logic to what I currently have? So when a user uploads a file, the file is automatically uploaded and saved in the backend. So if I choose to crop the image, should it only send the coordinates and recrop the images already saved?

Some logic flow and examples would be very much helpful. Thanks!

Comment: If you are sending the full image to the server no matter what you might want to just send the crop coordinates to the server and let the  server take care of cropping it. However, if you don't need to support older browsers you can do the cropping in the browser *before* you send the image to the server using the HTML5 File API, thus saving bandwidth and storage.

Comment: @Thayne I'm planning to support older browsers. Are you saying I have to send the crop coordinates through another request (not related to jquery fileupload), then crop the image on the backend?

Comment: There are probably other ways to do it, for example you could have the server send back the image, or a url to the image and manipulate that, but if you want to support IE9 or earlier, sending the coordinates and cropping in the backend is probably the simplest solution.

Comment: You could also use something like flash or (I cringe a little to say it) silverlight, or a even a Java applet.

Comment: I see, yep, I think I'll go with sending the coordinates and just do the cropping in the backend. You can post your comment as the answer if you want, so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to send two requests. You can create img tag and load your image through JavaScript and open image for cropping. Jcrop is also nice tool for image cropping which accept aspect ratio as parameter. Which returns you selected coordinates. And you can pass image and coordinates in one shot.